# str object not callable in python quiz

Tags: python, string

I am making a quiz and but it keeps saying str object not callable im guessing because ive already reassigned songn and guess but I dont know what to change

```
songn = str(song.readlines()[randNum]) #to match song line with artist
reader= csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
   print (songn[0]) #prints first letter of random song

artist = open("artistList.csv", "rt")
artistname = artist.readlines()[randNum] #to match song line with artist
print(artistname)
artist.close()
total=2 #number of guesses


guess = input("What is the song called?\n> ").lower()
print("guess is '%s' and songn is '%s'"(guess,songn))
```

the error is in this line

```
print("guess is '%s' and songn is '%s'"(guess,songn))
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the syntax of the line with function `print()`.

`print("guess is '%s' and songn is '%s'"(guess,songn))`

You should use '%' between the string and the variable to print

`print("guess is '%s' and songn is '%s'" % (guess,songn))`